# Implementing both AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate and AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate

Tags: swift, avfoundation, swift2

I am creating a class that implements both the `AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate` and the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` protocols in Swift 2 (beta 3), but I am getting a compiler error due to the fact that both protocols define very similar functions (intentionally so; there are example Objective-C classes that implement both protocols).

The conflicting protocol extensions are `AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate`'s [captureOutput(_:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate/captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:) and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`'s [captureOutput(_:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate/captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:). The only difference in the function signatures is the type of the `captureOutput` argument (`AVCaptureFileOutput` and `AVCaptureOutput` respectively).

I thought that using `AVCaptureFileOutput` in my function definition might work, since it is a subclass of `AVCaptureOutput`, but the compiler still reports the error:

```
Objective-C method 'captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:' provided by method 'captureOutput(_:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'captureOutput(_:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:)' in protocol 'AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate'
```

Is there a way to work around this, or to force the compiler to use the function for both protocols? Any idea if this is just a Swift 2.0 issue that should be reported, or an area where Swift has a different approach than what is normally used in Objective-C?

Thanks.

Comment: An alternative approach occurred to me. I was using the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to process and extract information from individual frames, while using AVCaptureMovieOutput to write audio/video to a file. Maybe I can just eliminate AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, since the capture delegate provides access to the sample buffer?

Comment: Never mind, the alternative doesn't seem to work. There is not an image buffer available if I try the above approach. I might just have to use two delegate classes.

Comment: Does the error occur if you use two separate extensions on the same class?

Comment: I have not tried with the latest version of Swift. But when I was originally writing this, it was not possible to contain the functions in different extensions, as the compiler still identified the conflicts during the compile process.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a workaround, at least given the current Swift beta. I instead used a separate class as the `AVCaptureFileOutputDelegate` delegate. Not elegant, but functional.